# Distribution in $L^p$ space with continuity

Tags: continuity, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Given $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, $T_f(\phi) = \int f(x)\phi(x)dx, \phi \in  L^p(\mathbb{R})$, I want to show that $T_f$ is continuous.

Since both $f,\phi \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$, they are continuous and satisfying the delta-epsilon definition. By definition, I need to show
$$
\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0,s.t. |x-y|<\delta, \Rightarrow |\int f(x)\phi(x)dx - \int f(y)\phi(y)dy|<\epsilon.
$$
I am confused on how to separate the integral and functions to use the continuity of $f, \phi$.

Any hint/help is appreciated.

Comment: Take $p=1$, $f(x)=\phi(x) = 1_{(0,\infty)}(x) {1 \over \sqrt{x}}$, then $T_f \phi$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about your knowledge of functional analysis. So i will try to use the epsilon delta method. Notice, you want to show that $T_f:L^p(\mathbb{R})\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous. Namely the domain you are working with is $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ not $\mathbb{R}$ (Note that your two integrals are the same with variable change $y=x$).

So to show continuity of $T_f$, you need to show
$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0,s.t. ||\phi_1-\phi_2||_{L^p}<\delta, \Rightarrow \left|\int f(x)\phi_1(x)dx - \int f(x)\phi_2(x)dy\right |<\epsilon.$$

Now see that $|\int f(x)\phi_1(x)dx - \int f(x)\phi_2(x)dx| \leq \int f(x)|\phi_1(x)-\phi_2(x)|dx$, by triangle inequality.

I will leave the rest for you to discover. Else, I can help out a bit more.